# Content larger than screen height

Tags: html, css

I've created a html file, with a header div, a content div and a footer div. The scrollbar should show up for the "bodyDiv" tag (and it does).

Now to my question: Why is the content inside the "bodxDiv" larger than the screen height? So the scrollbar appears - also if there is no need for it.

At the picture you can see, that the content ends after the red line, but there is stil a scrollbar

[image]

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bodyDiv">
      <div id="mainDiv">
        <div id="headDiv">Header</div>
        <div id="contentDiv">Content</div>
        <div id="footerDiv">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
<style type="text/css">
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html *
{
   color: #000;
   font-family: "Arial", Arial, sans-serif;
}

body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#bodyDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#mainDiv {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 18px auto;
}

#headDiv {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#contentDiv {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

#footerDiv {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle of OP's code http://jsfiddle.net/9YgLh/1/

Comment: `#mainDiv` has a height of 100% *and* a top and bottom margin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your body is overflowing because you give `#mainDiv` the property `height: 100%;`, which makes it take the full height, and then, you give it a top and bottom margin: `margin: 18px auto;`.

The CSS `margin` property adds space onto the outside of an element's box model to create spacing between an element and other elements nearby. If you want to maintain that appearance of spacing without the extra height, consider changing the property to `margin: 0 auto;`.

This will keep the horizontal centering that you have **without** adding extra height to the body, thus solving your problem.

Comment: that doesn't change anything

Comment: And how can I distance it from the horizontal browser borders? The distance gets lost when I do it like you said. And why does padding not work like it should in that case?

Comment: @Armin Glad you found the answer (I was out to lunch). Be careful using `flexbox`, though! It can be dangerous to use tools without understanding them :-)